# How to create cumulative precipitation vs. temperature graph in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have historical data for precip vs. annual temperature. I want to plot them into cool & wet, warm and wet, cool and dry, warm and dry years. Can someone help me with this?

```
Year    Precip  annual temperature
1987    821 8.5
1988    441 8
1989    574 7.9
1990    721 12.4
1991    669 10.8
1992    830 10
1993    1105    7.8
1994    772 8
1995    678 6.7
1996    834 8
1997    700 11
1998    786 11.2
1999    612 12
2000    758 10.6
2001    833 11
2002    622 10.6
2003    656 10.7
2004    799 9.9
2005    647 10.8
2006    764 12
2007    952 12.5
2008    943 10.86
2009    610 12.8
2010    766 11
2011    717 11.3
2012    602 9.5
2013    834 10.6
2014    758 11
2015    841 11
2016    630 11.5
2017    737 11.2
Average 742.32  10.36
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is just a scatterplot, isn't it? What are you having trouble with? We can help with problems, but usually are less enthusiastic about just writing all the code for you.

Comment: library(readxl)
weathergrid <- read_excel("weathergrid.xlsx")
mean_pcp <- mean(weathergrid$`Precipitation(mm)`)
mean_temp <- mean(weathergrid$`Average annual temperature©`)
weathergrid %>%
mutate(y1 = ifelse(Year < 2000, Year - 1900, Year - 2000)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=`Average annual temperature©`, y = `Precipitation(mm)`)) +
geom_text(aes(label =y1)) +
geom_vline(xintercept = mean_temp) +
geom_hline(yintercept = mean_pcp) + theme_light()

Comment: Sorry, for some reason my code was not working. This is what I tried:

Comment: library(readxl)
weathergrid <- read_excel("weathergrid.xlsx")
mean_pcp <- mean(weathergrid$`Precipitation(mm)`)
mean_temp <- mean(weathergrid$`Average annual temperature©`)
weathergrid %>%
mutate(y1 = ifelse(Year < 2000, Year - 1900, Year - 2000)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=`Average annual temperature©`, y = `Precipitation(mm)`)) +
geom_text(aes(label =y1)) +
geom_vline(xintercept = mean_temp) +
geom_hline(yintercept = mean_pcp) + theme_light()

Answer (score 0):

As Majid suggested, you need to give more detail so you can get better answers. At least, try to use `dput()` with your dataframe, so we can get a reproducible copy of it. Copying and pasting into Excel is not appropriate for these kind of questions.

In any case, that graph can be easily be done using the `ggplot2` package. You graph each year based on its X and Y coordinates and then manually add the lines and the titles for each category. You do need to establish the boundaries between cool/warm and dry/wet, of course.

```r
library(ggplot2)
rain <- read.csv('~/data/rain.csv')

limit_humid <- 800
limit_warm <- 9.5

ggplot(rain, aes(x = temp, y = precip)) +
    geom_text(aes(label = year)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = limit_warm) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = limit_humid) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and wet")', size = 4, parse = T,
             x = min(rain$temp), y = max(rain$precip)) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and wet")', size = 4, parse = T,
             x = max(rain$temp), y = max(rain$precip)) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Cool and dry")', size = 4, parse = T,
             x = min(rain$temp), y = min(rain$precip)) +
    annotate('text', label = 'bold("Warm and wet")', size = 4, parse = T,
             x = max(rain$temp), y = min(rain$precip)) +
    theme_classic() + 
    labs(x = 'Average Temperature (°C)',
         y = 'Cumulative precipitation (mm)')
```